# "Не" с относительными прилагательными

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как бы вы написали, описывая квартиру, слово *не угловая*, слитно или раздельно? Встречала слово *немеблированная*, написанное слитно, такое написание не режет глаз, тогда как *не угловая* написать слитно рука не поднимается.

Answer (score 4):

Не угловая комната - раздельно.

Вас могло смутить примечание 2 на сайте [Культура письменной речи](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53), не позволяющем одалживать с него цитаты...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как бы вы написали слово немеблированная, если оно употребляется в описании квартиры наряду с другими характеристиками. Например: Квартира сухая, солнечная, немеблированная. Ведь в данном предложении прилагательные - однородные сказуемые.

Comment: Да, напрашивается слитное написание: немеблированный - без мебели, примечание 1 (переход в качественные прилагательные); но неугловой?!

Comment: >> *А как бы вы написали слово немеблированная... Например: Квартира сухая, солнечная, немеблированная*   Я бы написал "скромненько, но со вкусом": Квартира сухая, солнечная, без мебели. "Немеблированная" мне шибко не нравится...

Comment: Она, зараза, хорошо гуглится. 8-( Особенно при продаже или сдаче квартир.

Comment: Про невкусное яблоко вообще сильно.